# In VBA, what is the return value of ActiveSheet.UsedRange if No UsedRange in activeSheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I read a VBA eample for selecting cells by value (In this case is selecting the cell which value is a negative number) in a Book named 'Excel 2019 power programming with vba' at page 243.

I am wondering that when there is a empty UsedRange, I select a single cell, the WorkRange Is NOT Nothing, so there is a massagebox "No cells qualify."  displayed. While I select a empty range,  If WorkRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub, as a result, there is no massagebox "No cells qualify."  displayed.

```
' Reduce the search to numeric cells only 
    On Error Resume Next
' As WorkRange.SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers) returns Error if no range is qualified.
    Set WorkRange = WorkRange.SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers)
    If WorkRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo 0
```

The code snippet:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectByValue()
    Dim Cell As Object
    Dim FoundCells As Range
    Dim WorkRange As Range

    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub
    
' Check all or selection?
    If Selection.CountLarge = 1 Then
    Set WorkRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
' If a single cell is selected, it checks all the used cell in a ActiveSheet
    Else
    Set WorkRange = Application.Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
' if a range is selected, it only check the selected range
End If
    
' For debug purpose
    Dim rngCell As Range
    For Each rngCell In WorkRange
        Debug.Print "1" & rngCell.Value
    Next rngCell



' Reduce the search to numeric cells only
    On Error Resume Next
' As WorkRange.SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers) returns Error if no range is qualified.
    Set WorkRange = WorkRange.SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers)
    If WorkRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo 0
    
' Loop through each cell, add to the FoundCells range if it qualifies
    For Each Cell In WorkRange
        If Cell.Value < 0 Then
            If FoundCells Is Nothing Then
                Set FoundCells = Cell
            Else
                Set FoundCells = Union(FoundCells, Cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell
    
' Show message, or select the cells
    If FoundCells Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No cells qualify."
    Else
        FoundCells.Select
        MsgBox "Selected " & FoundCells.Count & " cells."
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried to read the documentation of Microsoft and debug.print at VBE, but I still cannot find out the return value of `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` when there are all empty cells at a active sheet.

Comment: I like to use msg box to investigate the values of things.

Comment: `Debug.Print Activesheet.UsedRange.Address` will report the used range.  Try that on a new empty sheet, I think that will report `A1`

Answer (score 2):

When all cells are empty then `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` returns a `Range` object with the value of the single cell at A1. This is the case whether A1 is empty or not. This answer assumes that `ActiveSheet` actually exists.

Comment: When `WorkRange` is ActiveSheet.UsedRange returns a Range object with the value of the single cell at A1.
So,  the return value of `Set WorkRange = WorkRange.SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers)` is also  a Range object with the value of the single cell at A1?

Comment: If I understand what you are asking: if `WorkRange` is the single cell A1 and then you execute the line in your comment (with `On Error Resume Next` having been executed), then WorkRange must continue to be the single cell A1 because either: cell A1 contains a numeric constant and so WorkRange is re-assigned to be A1; or cell A1 does not contain a numeric constant and so the line of code errors (but code continues to be executed due to `On Error Resume Next`) meaning WorkRange is left being its pre-existing value of A1